# g++ -- missing array header

Tags: c++, gcc4

The following simple code can't be compiled by g++ 4.3:

```
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 8> myarray;

    return 0;
}
```

array: No such file or directory

Also, the compiler doesn't seen to understand option '-std=c++11' as is recommended to provide to the compiler. Is there another option?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe `std::array` was first added as part of TR1. If upgrading compilers is not an option, try changing the include to `#include <tr1/array>` and then use it as `std::tr1::array`

Comment: Praetorian, thanks it helped.

Comment: Can this comment be made an "answer". It works for people using older compilers!

Answer (score 2):

GCC 4.3 and presumably also your C++ library are too old for the support you're looking for.  You need a newer version.  Here's a [link to the GCC C++11 support page](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html), and another [link to the libstdc++ C++11 support page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html).

Alternatively, [clang](http://clang.llvm.org) supports all of C++11 with [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/).

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that it was a cross compiler that needed to be told where the sysroot was, and supplying `--sysroot=<path to sysroot>` allowed GCC to find the headers